# telebot.TeleBot.process_new_updates не обрабатывает сообщения

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, yandex-cloud

Я пишу telegram бота на [Yandex Cloud Functions](https://cloud.yandex.ru/services/functions) с помощью библиотеки [pyTelegramBotApi](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/index.html).
Вот мой код (упрощённый):

```
import os

import telebot
import json

MY_BOT: telebot.TeleBot

def message_handler(message: telebot.types.Message):
    MY_BOT.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text=message.text)

# Functions for Yandex.Cloud
def register_handlers(bot: telebot.TeleBot):
    """Registration all handlers before processing update."""

    bot.register_message_handler(callback=message_handler)


def process_event(event, bot):
    """
    Converting an Yandex.Cloud functions event to an update and
    handling tha update.
    """

    json_string = event['body']
    update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
    bot.process_new_updates([update])


def handler(event, context):
    """Yandex.Cloud functions handler."""

    if event['httpMethod'] == 'POST':

        global MY_BOT
        # Bot initialization
        MY_BOT = telebot.TeleBot(token=os.environ.get('TOKEN'))
        register_handlers(MY_BOT)
        process_event(event, MY_BOT)

        return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': 'ok'}
    return {'statusCode': 405}
```

Сначала я подумал, что глобальная переменная не изменяет своего значения, но [заглянув сюда](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/globalnye-peremennye-python#:%7E:text=%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20global%20.&text=%D0%97%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20c%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0,10%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20100.) поменял свое мнение.

Пробовал прокси, просто добавив

```
from telebot import apihelper
apihelper.proxy = {'https': 'https://x.x.x.x:port'}
```

Перед `MY_BOT = telebot.TeleBot(token=os.environ.get('TOKEN'))`

Пробовал также `telebot.TeleBot(token=os.environ.get('TOKEN'), threaded=False)`

Всё же осталось мнение, что до обработчика сообщения просто не доходит message.

Ошибку код не выдаёт, по логам функции:
[image: Логи Yandex Cloud Functions]

То есть `Update` заходит в `process_new_updates`, якобы обрабатывает и функция завершает свою работу. Прошу также заметить, что с aiogram всё работало, но в нем не достает register_next_step_handler(), который мне очень нужен.
К сожалению не могу сейчас найти github с кодом aiogram, чтобы показать, что там было подобно написано и всё работало.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать пример из их репозитория:
https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/serverless/aws_lambda_function.py

Я только функцию-хендлер переименовал и всё завелось. Часа за 3 прототип накидал. Использовал вместе с api-gateway.